# how to get rid of Nontype array

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, binary

I want to have an array with random binary values, its length is p, but I get the error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

this is my code

```
import random
def length(p): 
    binary = [] 
    for i in range(p): 
        temp = random.randint(0, 1)
        binary.append(temp )    
    print(binary) 
fn=length(5)
fn.type
```

Comment: While line throws this error?

Answer (score 1):

Hi firstly you didn't return any value

```py
def length(p): 
    binary = [] 
    for i in range(p): 
        temp = random.randint(0, 1)
        binary.append(temp )    
    print(binary) 
    
    return binary # Add return here
```

Secondly type is used like this

```py
fn.type # Change this
type(fn) # To this
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` has no return statement, so it can't return anything. When functions in Python don't return anything, attempting to set a variable to their return value sets the variable to `None`. Therefore, `something=length(something_else)` is equivalent to `something=None`. Thus, `None.type` will fail because the `None` singleton doesn't have a `type` attribute.

The solution is to add a return statement to your function. You probably meant to add `return binary` to the end. However a `list` still doesn't have a `type` attribute. You may have meant to do `type(fn)`, which is the correct way in Python to get the type of something.